# Can I use a text value to selectToggle()?

Tags: javafx, radio-button

I am using a text file to load information to a javafx gui.  Is there a way I can use a text value there to select a radio button in a toggle group.

I think '''toggleGroup.selectedValue(toggle value)''' is the function I need, but it does not take a string. Is there a way to convert the string to a toggle value, indirectly?

The following does not work because '''selectToggle()''' takes a toggle not a text value and neither an implicit nor explicit '''(toggle)''' cast seem to work.

`tgrpSex.selectToggle(read.nextLine());`

This should be reproducible:

```
package programmingassignment1;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
//import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
//import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*; //input/output
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.*; //scanner, user input
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
//import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;

public class Address extends Application {


    RadioButton rbMale = new RadioButton("Male");
    RadioButton rbFemale = new RadioButton("Female");
    ToggleGroup tgrpSex = new ToggleGroup();


    GridPane rootPane = new GridPane();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){

//Setting an action for the Open Contact  button       
        Button btOpenContact = new Button("Open Contact");
        File file = new File("AddressBook.txt");

        btOpenContact.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                openContact(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
//Setting an action for the Save button        
        Button btSave = new Button("Save");

        btSave.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                    try{saveContact(file);}
                    catch(Exception f){f.getMessage();}
        }});



        //associate radio buttons with a toggle group
        rbMale.setToggleGroup(tgrpSex);
        rbFemale.setToggleGroup(tgrpSex);

        rbMale.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(rbMale.isSelected()){int maleContact = 1;}
        });
        rbFemale.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(rbFemale.isSelected()){int maleContact = 0;}
        });

      rootPane.add(new Label("Sex"), 3, 1);
        rootPane.add(rbFemale, 3, 2);
        rootPane.add(rbMale, 3, 3);       

        rootPane.add(btOpenContact, 1, 13);

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 1000, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Address Book");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
    }

 public void saveContact(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, Exception{ //declaration
                //this code might cause a FileNotFoundException
                //if it does it creates an exception object of the above type
        try{
                    //PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter (file);
                    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(file);
                    output.println(tfContactFirst.getText());
                    output.println(tfContactLast.getText());
                    output.println(tfSpouseFirst.getText());
                    output.println(tfSpouseLast.getText());
                    output.println(cboWorkHome.getValue());
                    output.println(tfStreet.getText());
                    output.println(tfCity.getText());
                    output.println(tfState.getText());
                    output.println(tfZip.getText());
                    output.close();
                }
                //what do do with exception
                //here the catch clause with create another exception
                //that is passed the result of the getMessage() method from the original exception
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                    throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                }
    }

//read same text file you save too
    public void openContact(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, Exception{
        try{
            Scanner read = new Scanner(file);     
            while(read.hasNextLine()){
                //how do I save the imageFileName
                 tfContactFirst.setText(read.nextLine());
                 tfContactLast.setText(read.nextLine());
                 tgrpSex.selectToggle(read.nextLine());
                 tfSpouseFirst.setText(read.nextLine());
                 tfSpouseLast.setText(read.nextLine());
                 //tfSpouseGender.setText(read.nextLine());
                 cboWorkHome.setValue(read.nextLine());
                 tfStreet.setText(read.nextLine());
                 tfCity.setText(read.nextLine());
                 tfState.setText(read.nextLine());
                 tfZip.setText(read.nextLine());
                 //taNotes.setText(read.nextLine());
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                    throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

No results <- syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. I got the answer. I didn't know what a toggle type object was. I looked up an examples of selectToggle() and learned you can pass a radio button object to it. So I put that in an if then statement. `if(read.nextLine().equals("Male")){tgrpSex.selectToggle(rbMale);}
             else{tgrpSex.selectToggle(rbFemale);}`